# JDBC update - NotSerializableException

Tags: spring, jdbc, java

Привет. Это код из примера [Spring MVC step-by-step](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step). После того, как я заменил устаревший SimpleJdbcDaoSupport на JdbcDaoSupport, метод saveProduct стал бросать NotSerializableException. В интернете нагуглил решение (закоменченная строка), но не нашёл решение с именованными параметрами. Получается, JdbcDaoSupport не поддерживает их?

```
public class JdbcProductDao extends JdbcDaoSupport implements ProductDao {

...

    public void saveProduct(Product prod) {
        logger.info("Saving product: " + prod.getDescription());
        int count = getJdbcTemplate().update(
                "update products set description = :description, price = :price where id = :id",
                new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("description", prod.getDescription())
                        .addValue("price", prod.getPrice())
                        .addValue("id", prod.getId()));
        //int count = getJdbcTemplate().update("update products set description = ?, price = ? where id = ?",prod.getDescription(),prod.getPrice(),prod.getId());
        logger.info("Rows affected: " + count);
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получается, не поддерживает. И вообще, лучше уж Hibernate использовать.

<s>Как же я люблю сам себе отвечать</s>